# Only allow specific users to create Sharepoint sites?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions

I enabled the `Show the Create site command to users who have permissions to create sites` in the Sharepoint Administration Center, but where is it that I define which users have these privileges?

Comment: How can you turn on this? I can't even see it as an option in the Sharepoint Admin center under Settings.

Answer (score 3):

This is controlled by the Permission Levels the user has on a given site. You can manage this for a site by navigating to **Site Settings** and selecting **Site Permissions** under **Users and Permissions**. If a given user or a group they belong to has a permission level with the Create Subsite permission, they can create subsites on a given site.

For more about permission levels, check out [this technet article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721640.aspx).

Comment: They don't have any explicit permissions, though. Yet they are still able to create sites on the main page, as the button is clearly visible, i.e. it's imposing no restriction.

Comment: Have you tried the check permissions option on the site permissions page? You can use this to audit a particular users permissions and see where they're getting them from. You may have them in a group which does have permissions enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a group and provide site creator & contributor access and add respective user to in that group.